# Not logging on requests with (Clojure) http-kit

Tags: logging, clojure, http-kit

Is it possible to not log errors on failed requests with the Clojure library http-kit, that is, on the client side. My app is using it to ping other services and them being down is not really an error.

Comment: this can be set using the logging library you are using. If you paste in an actual log message we will be able to recommend a specific log configuration. Please include the logging library you are using (logj, timber, etc.)